# Why the result of “bag” > “apple” is True in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.6

Why the result of “bag” > “apple” is True in Python?
I tried this code below i don't know why it show this result and how? Please some one explain it.

print("bag" > "apple")

True

Comment: Strings are sorted using [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (i.e. alphabetical order). See the linked question above. In your example `'b'` is after `'a'` in the alphabet, therefore it is "greater".

Comment: Please explain it deeply

Comment: print(ord("b")) -> 98
print(ord("a")) -> 97 for that reason b > a right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is `True` because Python compares the first letter of each word. And `b` is greater than `a` in Python.

Comment: But point is how "b" is greater than "a"?

Comment: "b" comes after "a" in the alphabet (which is why the corresponding ASCII values have the same relationship).

Comment: print(ord("b")) -> 98
print(ord("a")) -> 97 for that reason b > a right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is definitely a duplicate; it's best to avoid answering, so that it's easier to close and then the original question is easier to find by searching. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer - *Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which... ...have already been asked and answered many times before.* - By the way, your answer makes it sound like Python *only* compares the first letter of each word, which is not always true.